# Chrome HTML5 file input type memory leak (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ember.js, memory-leaks

In a mobile web application that heavily uses chrome's local storage I noticed I ran out on space too quickly after a while while taking pictures and storing them. 
I set up a barebone Ember application with a single file input type to narrow the problem:

**index.hbs**

```
<form>
  <input id="file" type="file" accept="image//*" capture="camera">
</form>

<button id="clear" {{action "reset"}}>
  Clear File input
</button>
```

**index.js (controller)**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    reset: function(){
      Ember.$('#file').wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
      Ember.$('#file').unwrap();
    }
  }
});
```

When accessed from a tablet it will display three options to upload a file: **Documents**, **Camcorder** and **Camera**. When files are uploaded from the first two the **Data** of Chrome app won't increase as it is temporarily stored until further operations (e.g. storing it locally via the Local Storage API).

[image]

However, when pictures are uploaded using the **Camera**, the **Data** memory will increase and will never be released, even if for example we take another picture or upload another file. Each picture taken increases memory that will never be freed, not even refreshing or closing & reopening the browser, the only way is to Clear Data.

Logic in the controller was in hope of when clearing the input field memory would be released but it is not the case.

Chrome version is **49.0.2623.105 (Official Build) (32-bit)**

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome bug

Comment: Able to reproduce. Definitely a Chrome bug.

Comment: I was hoping this would be my mistake so anything could be done. Is there somewhere where I can open an Issue, a ticket, etc.. for chrome?